# Como mover form no ecrã programaticamente com efeito animado?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso fazer a minha form ir por da localização 0,0 para a localização 100,100 no ecrã sem a interação do usuário, ou seja por meio da programação, este movimento precisa ser animado, ou seja não pode desaparecer de um ponto e ir para outro, precisa parecer que se moveu até lá.

Comment: Olá Pedro. Sua pergunta está meio confusa. Poderia explicar melhor o que deseja? Se possível, adicionando um exemplo ou o código que já possui?

Comment: @Randrade Quero saber como posso fazer com que a form se mova sozinha no ecrã. eu já tentai isto mas não dá Location.X = 1000; Location.Y = 1000;

Comment: Você quer um efeito animado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim quero por a form a movesse no ecrã

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que a forma mais simples para fazer o que deseja é utilizar a `library` [WinFormAnimation](http://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/).

Para instalar, basta usar o seguinte comando o `Package Manager Console`:

> Install-Package WinFormAnimation

Feito isso, basta usar o seguinte código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Animator2D(new Path2D(new Float2D(-100, -100), this.Location.ToFloat2D(), 500))
        .Play(this, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location);
}
```

Onde `this` é o `Form` atual, mas você pode alterar para qualquer elemento (outro `form`, button, text, etc).

Para maiores detalhes, olhe a [documentação oficial](http://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/).

Na mesma pergunta que o [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156332/20615) postou, possui [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37328138/4843158) que também pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Que solução elegante e limpa +1 :)

Comment: Funciona :)!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi você quer um efeito animado quando o elemento é movido, encontrei esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103677/1518921

Crie/declare a seguinte classe:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Util {
    public enum Effect { Roll, Slide, Center, Blend }

    public static void Animate(Control ctl, Effect effect, int msec, int angle) {
        int flags = effmap[(int)effect];
        if (ctl.Visible) { flags |= 0x10000; angle += 180; }
        else {
            if (ctl.TopLevelControl == ctl) flags |= 0x20000; 
            else if (effect == Effect.Blend) throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        flags |= dirmap[(angle % 360) / 45];
        bool ok = AnimateWindow(ctl.Handle, msec, flags);
        if (!ok) throw new Exception("Animation failed");
        ctl.Visible = !ctl.Visible;
    }

    private static int[] dirmap = { 1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 10, 8, 9 };
    private static int[] effmap = { 0, 0x40000, 0x10, 0x80000 };

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr handle, int msec, int flags);
}
```

E para usa-la faça algo como:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Util.Animate(form1, Util.Effect.Slide, 150, 180);
}
```

Comment: O programa diz que é um tipo e não pode ser usado no contexto

Comment: @Pedro não sei o que quer dizer, tem que colocar o erro exato que ocorre, o randrade editou e corrigiu, veja se foi falta das classes.

Comment: nesta parte `Util.Animate(form1, Util.Effect.Slide, 150, 180);` o form1 diz que form 1 é um type  que está fora de contexto eu já tentei form1 Form1 Form form e todos dão erro

Comment: @Pedro Mas form1 é um exemplo, pensei que fosse intuitivo para quem usa VS, mas ok, troque form1 pelo form ou janela que deseja mover.

Comment: A form chamasse form1

Comment: @Pedro chamou o `Util.Animate(form1, Util.Effect.Slide, 150, 180);` aonde?

Comment: @Pedro Se você passar o erro exato vai ser mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: @Pedro o randrade me disse que talvez para o seu caso tenha que fazer isto `Util.Animate(this, Util.Effect.Slide, 100, 100);`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já não está a dar aquele erro agora esta a dar outro vou ver o que se passa